# UDF Error when trying to pick up the .py file

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I've followed the instructions [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/udfs.html) and everything went smoothly until I got to clicking on `Import Python UDFs` when 
I got the following error:

> Run-time error '1004': Cannot run the macro 'xlwings-test.xlsm!ImportPythonUDFs'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

[image]

Of course I enabled `Trust access to the VBA project object model` as I should have.
Also, when I type `ALT+F11` I see that xlwings.xlam is loaded.

Excel version: 15.0.4779.1001 64-bit, xlwings version 0.6.2, Win 8.1.

Comment: Do you have the xlwings module present in the Excel file? the add-in alone is not enough.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean by that..

Comment: thanks @pnuts, I've updated my question accordingly

Comment: The add-in is not a replacement (yet) for the xlwings VBA module. Download the udf sample from the homepage and try again. Or start from the template.

Comment: I used `xlwings template open` in order to create a new file - is that ok?

Comment: Sure. if the issue doesn't resolve please open an issue on GitHub so we can keep the number of comments low here.

Comment: Sure, no problem. It's at: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by some non-standard characters in the file name (like spaces, dashes). It will be fixed with the next release. For now just rename the file.

Comment: This has now been released with xlwings v0.6.4